# How do you associate a named branch with a different changeset in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I converted a repository from Git to Mercurial, and created a named branch `production` for our production development.  Unfortunately, a week later, we've just realized the `production` branch is on the wrong changeset.

Although we've made a number of changes to the repository, there haven't been any commits to the `production` branch yet.  I need to somehow reassociate the `production` name with the correct changeset, or delete the branch and recreate it.

What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, very easily, by using the `mq` extension.  Obviously, this requires everyone to get a new clone of the repository.

If the `production` branch was created in changeset 869, and you wanted it on changeset 842, you can say:

```
hg strip 869
hg update 842
hg branch production
```

This will remove changeset 869 (and all its descendants) from the repository, renumbering any subsequent changesets to fill in the gaps, and then assign the `production` name to the correct changeset.

Answer (score 0):

If there have been no "commits to the `production` branch yet" then the branch doesn't yet exist.  In mercurial's named branches a branch name is an indelible label on a committed changeset.  A changeset never changes what branch it's on.  I'm going to assume you've got at least one changeset with the `production` branch label or this turns into a no-problem question.

If you take these actions I think you'll end up okay:

1. `hg update` to the revision you wish was the production head
2. `hg branch production` this just says the next commit should have the production label
3. `hg commit` you'll now have a new commit with the label `production`

Now when people do a clone of just production:

```
hg clone repopath#production
```

or

```
hg clone -r production repopath
```

or update to it

```
hg update production
```

They'll get the branch of development you want.  That old changeset(s) will still (and always will) have the `production` label, but that's likely okay.  If it's really not okay you could rebuild the repo and remove the labels from those commits, but the process above gets people cloning/updating `production` the right stuff, so you should be fine.

Comment: I just tried this, and it doesn't work.  `hg branch production` says "abort: a branch of the same name already exists (use 'hg update' to switch to it)"